# ReactJs Complex Sidebar with nested components and state management

Tags: reactjs, rendering, sidebar, unity-webgl

I am using reactJs with Mui to implement a portal for a unity project that creates metaverses, I have a floating sidebar that will contain all the elements and objects for the user to use and manipulate.

here is the wireframe

[wireframe of the sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgqt4.png)

The problem is that this sidebar has a lot of states and components to render conditionally (it is more like the canva sidebar)
My question is what is the best approach to achieve this result:
[when the user clicks on see all 3D assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kls4M.png)

[when the user clicks see all furniture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzaxM.png)

[when the user clicks on certain object on the canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDMYG.png)

How to be able to show categorized objects and see them all and manipulate objects settings inside this sidebar component, It is getting more and more complex beside the presence of the webgl

If you know a good approach to follow please help me

Thank you!

I tried conditional rendering but the component got complicated so I separated it into multiple component. But I need an effective way to change the content of the sidebar based on the requirements provided before

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Consider embedding the images into the post. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a dynamic Sidebar component which takes in a few parameters. Then you can design an enum to render the tab.

```html
const tabEnumList = [
  { 
    name: "Furniture",
    items: [
      {
        icon: <TableIcon />
        name: "Table"
      }
    ]
  },
  
]
```

You can add more items and tabs like that structure, then put it into Sidebar component as parameters